# Can spidermonkey be compiled without math support?

Tags: c, spidermonkey, javascript-engine

My libm does not have sin and cos functions.

Is there a configuration switch that enables me to compile spidermonkey without the Math.* function of JavaScript?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can write stub (dummy) functions to avoid the compilation/link errors..

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to implement sin/cos in a helper file than to remove Math from javascript.